# Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

Tags: iphone

```
0x90938ef6  <+0010>  jae    0x90938f06 <__kill+26>
```

The line about crashes the program and says:

> Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

How do I fix it?

Comment: Please show some code and context about what are you trying to do, version of iOS, etc. It is almost impossible to help you without something else.

Comment: Joseph800 -- this question is impossible to answer in its current form. When you ask questions here on Stack Overflow, be sure you're providing sufficient context for people so we can help you.

Comment: Just want to add that I have the same bug twice. Each time I have no choice but to rewrite the program from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is some debugging guides.

- [Xcode Debugging Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/000-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007057)
- [iOS Development Guide: Debugging Applicaitons](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/xcode/conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH7-SW1)